# Como obter o valor de um input HTML e colocar em um atributo "href"?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<h2>Pesquisar Usuários</h2>

<form action="">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <a href="#" onclick="window.open('/Usuarios/Usuario?id=' + input)" target"_blank">Buscar</a>
</form>

<script>
    var input = document.getElementsByName('name').values
</script>
```

A saída é esta:

```
https://localhost:44339/Usuarios/Usuario?id=function%20values()%20{%20[native%20code]%20}
```

Quando meu objetivo era obter esta saída, por exemplo:

```
https://localhost:44339/Usuarios/Usuario?id=1
```

Já tentei obter o valor de tudo que foi forma.

Comment: Seu código tem erros no **Html**: target está faltando um =, e no **Js** document.GetElementsByName retorna uma **`NodeList`**, ou seja, um array com vários elementos com aquele *name*, mesmo que no Html só exista 1, então terá que pegar o input assim (document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value) além de como pode ver tbm é **`value`** e não values!

Comment: <h2>Pesquisar Usuários</h2>

    <input type="number" id="pesquisa" name="pesquisa">
    <a href="#" onclick="window.open('/Usuarios/Usuario?id=' + input)" target="_blank">Buscar</a>

<script>
    var input = document.getElementsByName('pesquisa')[0].value
</script>                                                                                                                                                    O meu código está assim agora e o link está saindo sem o valor que eu coloco no input: https://localhost:44339/Usuarios/Usuario?id=

Comment: Se o input tem a entrada de nome como a url montada sera o final id. https://localhost:44339/Usuarios/Usuario?id=1... não seria https://localhost:44339/Usuarios/nome_usuario .... a capturado da saira do input sera o nome digitado  e não sera retornado um numero a não o que procurar entender é uma consulta pelo nome que retorna o id.

Comment: Da uma realçada na sua duvida talves eu posso ajudar.

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que isto resolve seu problema:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Pesquisar Usuários</h2>

        <form action="#">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
            <button onclick="buscarUsuarios()">Buscar</button>
        </form>
        
        <script>
            function buscarUsuarios() {
                let inputValue = document.querySelector('#name').value;
                window.open('/Usuarios/Usuario?id=' + inputValue);
            }
        </script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

### Problemas

- Tentativa de selecionar o input pelo método `document.getElementsByName`, que retorna um array-like, e não o elemento HTML diretamente.
- Expectativa de acessar o valor retornado por uma propriedade "values", que não existe

### Soluções

- Selecionar o input pelo seu ID, através de `document.querySelector`, que já retorna o elemento HTML diretamente
- Obter o valor do input por meio da propriedade `value`

Answer (score -2):

Se você deseja obter o valor do campo de entrada HTML e usá-lo para construir um link no atributo href, há alguns ajustes que você precisa fazer em seu código JavaScript. Aqui está uma versão corrigida do seu código:

```
<h2>Pesquisar Usuários</h2>

<form action="">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <a href="#" onclick="buscarUsuario()">Buscar</a>
</form>

<script>
    function buscarUsuario() {
        // Obter o valor do campo de entrada
        var input = document.getElementById('name').value;

        // Construir o URL com o valor do campo
        var url = '/Usuarios/Usuario?id=' + input;

        // Abrir a URL em uma nova janela
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    }
</script>
```

Aqui estão as alterações que foram feitas:

Substituí document.getElementsByName('name').values por document.getElementById('name').value para corretamente obter o valor do campo de entrada.

Alterei a chamada da função window.open para ocorrer dentro de uma função chamada buscarUsuario(). Isso permite que a função seja chamada corretamente quando o botão "Buscar" é clicado.

No HTML, alterei onclick="window.open('/Usuarios/Usuario?id=' + input)" para onclick="buscarUsuario()" para chamar a função buscarUsuario() quando o link é clicado.

Agora, quando você digitar algo no campo de entrada e clicar no link "Buscar", ele abrirá uma nova janela com a URL construída usando o valor do campo de entrada.